# Passing Scope from one function to another

Tags: javascript, scope

I have an object litrel that has 2 anonymous functions defined as such:

```
obj = {
    funcA : function(){
        var a = 'a';
    },
    funcB : function(){
        // but how do you access the scope in 'funcA' to access variable 'a'?
        console.log(a)
    }
}
```

I do not want to pass any variables just the scope of 'funcA' - thoughts?

Comment: You can't. What is your original problem? Why do you need this scope transfer?

Comment: As Max said - you can't. Variable `a` is local to scope of funcA, scopes aren't "transferable".

Comment: There is an excellent article on how scope chains are created in Richard Cornford's article on [Javascript Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clScCh). You can't reference an activation or variable object, so you can't pass "scope" from one function to another.

Comment: @RobG You can access the variable object when its the global object though, right? As in, the variable object in global code is `window`?

Comment: @Alex - touché, the global object is a special case. It can be put on top of the scope chain using *with*, but that is a risky thing to do if you are not in full control of the environment.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript scope doesn't work like that because it has (only) function scope (except when using the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword).

What you *could* do is...

```
obj = {
    a: 0,
    funcA: function() {
        this.a = 'a';
    },
    funcB: function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKghw/).

Comment: that is possible but I do have a large amount of variables, objects to access from funcA(). the scope of funcA is what I require access of from funcB. to note I would like to have it also work in the new ECMAscript version as well.

Comment: @quinton: I think you need to do some study on Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: But property resolution using *this* is very different to identifier resolution on a scope chain. Since *this* is set by the call, the above method requires very careful calling. Probably better to just use object properties as "variables" and pass that object around.

Comment: @RobG Are you talking about the fragility of an indirect call to `funcB()` losing its `this` context? You should answer with your suggestion, I'm not 100% sure I know what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just saying that passing a variable object to put on top of the scope chain is quite different to setting *this* to certain value. Onde deals with identifier resolution, the other property resolution. And using *this* in an object literal is problematic as the function might not be called as a method of the object. Perhaps a closure is best for the OPs requirements. I'll think on it more…

Answer (score 1):

You can use the a closure with the module pattern to get access to variables in an outer scope. More than one function can accesses the variable:

```
var obj = (function() {

  var a;

  return {

    setA: function(value) {
      a = value;
      return a;
    },

    getA: function(value) {
      return a;
    },

    multiplyA: function(value) {
      a = a * value;
      return a;
    }
  };
}());


alert(    obj.setA(5)      );  // 5
alert(    obj.multiplyA(2) );  // 10
alert(    obj.getA()       );  // 10
```

See Douglas Crockford's article on [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html). In this way, functions can share a common variable object on their scope chain. You still can't reference it or pass it to another function, but you might be able to get the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks @RobG, yes I know of the module pattern, although a great solution in respect to good coding it is not quite what I am after. looking to access members defined inside funcA from funcB without having to have the members located outside of the 2 functions not to pass them as arguments such as individually or as an array - passing the scope from funcA to funcB. never seen this done before.

Comment: I think the above using the module pattern and a private member is as close as I can get it for now to what I am after, however being able to pass the scope from one function to another without the need of a global member variable would be of great use.... something to think about :)  Thanks RobG for your input!

Comment: Just to note, Rob's answer is the closest however as it is not 'exactly' what I am after I won't be setting it as 'the' answer. still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code do what you want? If not, I'm really curious as to why.

```
obj = {
    funcA : function(){
        this.a = 'a';
        alert(this.a);
    },
    funcB : function(){
        // but how do you access the scope in 'funcA' to access variable 'a'?
        alert(this.a);
    }
}

obj.funcA();
obj.funcB();
```

What is the difference between accessing the actual scope of a separate function and setting members on the parent object as I have done?

Also, since there isn't a way of passing scope, are you just going to use something similar to this code instead?